# why the time taken to execute same javascript code varies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, underscore.js

**See the Console the time varies each time I dont know why**

I am trying to execute a function and get the time taken by it, I have used console.time(), but each time when I run it shows different time
One more thing, Is time taken by underscore is more than normal execution time.

```js
function map(){
  
  console.time('mycode');
  
  var arr = [234345345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,5445645,456456,456456,234,467,234234234,456,43535,456,12,3123123123,456,456456,1231235,6456456,234,234456,4,5632452344,65,543452334124436,2345,345346,2345];
  var result = [];
  var constant = 3;
  var length = arr.length; //will avoid calculation of length each time
  for(i=0;i<length;i++){
   temp = arr[i] * constant;
   result.push(temp);
  }
  
  console.timeEnd('mycode');
  
  console.time('mycode1');
  
  var underscore = _.map([arr], function(num){ return num * 3; });
  
  console.timeEnd('mycode1');
 }
 
 function where(){
  
  console.time("myCode");
  var arr =  [{title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
   
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1613},
   {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1615}
  ];
  var author = 'Shakespeare';
  var year = '1611';
  var result = [];
  var length = arr.length; //will avoid calculation of length each time
  for(i=0;i<length;i++){ //you know that and takes more time than or statement
   if(arr[i]['author'] == author && arr[i]['year'] == year){
    result.push(arr[i]);
   }
  }
  console.log(result)
  console.timeEnd("myCode");
  
  console.time("myCode1");
  var underscore = _.filter(arr, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611});
  
  console.log(underscore)
  console.timeEnd("myCode1");
 }
```

```css
.container{
  width:calc(100% - 200px);
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#f4f4f4;
 }
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>

<h1>Evaluating time </h1>
<input type='button' onclick='map()' value='Execute'>
<input type='button' onclick='where()' value='Execute'>
```

Comment: Why do you have an expectation that it will be constant? Computers aren't that stable, the time will always vary at least a little bit.

Comment: if it var atleast a bit its okay but sometimes it gives 1.565ms and sometimes .056 ms.. this is not a slight difference right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time taken to execute code will vary due to other work that is being performed by your CPU. Interrupts are constantly occurring because of other processes running on the computer. Your web application is just one of the many applications requiring a slice of CPU time. There are also factors like caching that gets performed by the CPU for frequently requested data, as well as OS caches.

Comment: I am satisfied with your answer but can you explain me why underscore takes more time than normal execution,and while printing the results in console window the condition reverses

Comment: @Karthikeyansundaramoorthi The underscore `_map` function conforms to functional programming principles in that it doesn't cause any side effects to the array passed in. Instead, a transformation function is applied to each element and a new array is returned. The underlying code to produce such behaviour is more complex, involving more memory and processing. You would get faster performance using `_each` instead, but that will produce side effects.